# JQuery UI sortable receive event doesn't capture drops within the same list. Which event does?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Using JQuery UI sortable, I have an ajax call on the "receive" event.  That captures dragging and dropping a card from one list to another.  However, it does not capture dragging a card from within a list to a different place in the list.  Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function linkUp() {
    $("#IssueList25").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var droppedIssueId = ui.item.attr("id");
            var destListId = this.id;
            var sourceListId = ui.sender[0].id;
            var destList = $('#IssueList25').sortable('toArray').toString();

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: "Lists.aspx",
                data:"event=receive&sourceListId = " + sourceListId + "&destListId = " + destListId + "&droppedIssueId=" + droppedIssueId + "&destList=" + destList,
                dataType: "text"
            });
        }
    });});
</script>
```

Is there a different event that gets fired when dropping the card inside the same list?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the answer is "out", although it does fire twice for the drag from one list to another.